# How to set up a search bar using Spring Boot, JPA and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, search, thymeleaf

So, I have a spring web app, it's a simple form to enter classes, lecturers, etc... Now I need a simple search bar for these classes which will return results which match the subject of a class.

This is my code, and what I have done so far.

Lecture.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Lecture")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Lectureimplements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Lecturer.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name="Lecture_Lecturer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lecture"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lecturer"))
    private Lecturer lecturer;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Subject is empty!")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Subject must be from 2 to 50 letters long!")
    @Column(name="subject")
    private String subject;

    @NotEmpty(message = "You haven't entered a short description!")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 150, message = "A short description must be from 2 to 150 letters long!")
    @Column(name="description")
    private String shortDescription;

    @NotNull(message = "You haven't picked a lecture type!")
    @Column(name="type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LectureType lectureType;

    @Column(name="published")
    private Boolean published;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="creationDate")
    private Date creationDate;


    public enum LectureType {

        PRACTICE, PRESENTATION
    }
}
```

LectureController.java

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping
@SessionAttributes({"types", "positions", "lectureList", "published"})
public class LectureController {

    @Autowired
    LectureRepository lectureR;

    @Autowired
    LecturerRepository lecturerR;

    List<Lecture> lectureList = new ArrayList<>();

    @RequestMapping
    public String newLecture() {

        return "newLecture";
    }

    @GetMapping("/newLecture")
    public String showForm(Model model, Lecture lecture) {

        log.info("Filling data to show form.");

        model.addAttribute("lecture", new Lecture());
        model.addAttribute("types", Lecture.LectureType.values());
        model.addAttribute("positions", Lecturer.LecturerPositions.values());
        model.addAttribute("published", lecture.getPublished());

        return "newLecture";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allLectures")
    public String showLectures() {

        return "allLectures";
    }

    @GetMapping("/resetCounter")
    public String /resetCounter(SessionStatus status) {

        lectureList.clear();
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/newLecture";
    }

    @PostMapping("/novoPredavanje")
    public String processForm(@Valid Lecture lecture, Errors errors, Model model) {

    log.info("Processing lecture: " + lecture);

    if(errors.hasErrors()) {

        log.info("Lecture has errors. Ending.");

        return "newLecture";

    } else {

        lectureList.add(lecture);

        model.addAttribute("numberOfLectures", lectureList.size());

        model.addAttribute("lecture", lecture);

        model.addAttribute("published", lecture.getPublished());

        model.addAttribute("lectureList", lectureList);

        log.info("Lecture successfully saved: " + lecture);

        return "output";
    }
}

    @GetMapping("/lectureSearch")
    public String lectureSearch(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("lecture", new Lecture());

        return "lectureSearch";
    }

    @PostMapping("/lectureSearch")
    public String lectureSearch(Lecture lecture, Model model, String subject) {

        List<Lecture> foundLectures = lectureR.findBySubject(subject);
        model.addAttribute("foundLectures", foundLectures);

        return "lectureSearch";
    }
}
```

LectureRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface LectureRepository extends CrudRepository<Lecture, Long> {

    List<Lecture> findBySubject(String subject);
}
```

lectureSearch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" >
        <title>Lecture output</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img th:src="@{~/images/picture.png}" />

        <form action="/resetCounter">
            <input type="submit" value="Reset counter" class="btn btn-warning" style="background-color: orange"/>
        </form>

        <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
            <a th:href="@{/newLecture}" class="btn btn-primary">Enter a new lecture</a>
            <a th:href="@{/svaPredavanja}" class="btn btn-primary">All lectures</a>
            <a th:href="@{/pretragaPredavanja}" class="btn btn-primary">Lecture search</a>
        </div>

        <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
            <form method="POST" th:action="@{/logout}">You are logged in as <span sec:authentication="name">User</span>.
                <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <div><h3>Lecture search</h3></div>
        <form th:object="${lecture}" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
                <input type="text" name="lectureSearch" th:value="${lectureSearch}">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
        </form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Short description</th>
                <th>Lecture Type</th>
                <th>Lecturer's Name</th>
                <th>Lecturer's position</th>
                <th>Published</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="lecture : ${lectureSearch}">
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.subject}" >LECTURE.SUBJECT</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.shortDescription}" >LECTURE.SHORTDESCRIPTION</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.lectureType}" >LECTURE.LECTURETYPE</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.lecturer.name}" >LECTURER.NAME</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.lecturer.lecturerPosition}" >LECTURER.LECTURERPOSITION</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${lecture.published}" >LECTURE.PUBLISHED</span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Upon entering a subject in the search bar, no results can be seen, even though a lecture with the queried subject exists. Checking in the debugger, the variable `subject` is null even after the user types in the subject he wants to search for. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have in your template:

```
<tr th:each="lecture : ${lectureSearch}">
```

But you are adding to the model

```
 model.addAttribute("foundLectures", foundLectures);
```

So your table should be

```
<tr th:each="lecture : ${foundLectures}">
```

Additionally the binding of the form input field is wrong.
This should be

```
<form th:object="${lecture}" method="post">
   <div>
       <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
       <input type="text" name="subject" th:field="*{subject}">
       <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </div>
</form>
```

For more information please read the manual: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Comment: still doesn't work; I believe the problem is that the variable `subject` is null when searching and I don't know how to solve that problem

Comment: I added the fix for the form you have to do. The question still persist is if you call POST or GET for search.

Comment: I've tried with field, now it's giving me this error: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "lectureSearch" - line 35, col 48)

Comment: you haven't change the whole form as I wrote in my answer. The field must be subject not lecutreSearch

Comment: sorry, you are right, I'm blind... didn't replace the dollar sign `$` with the star `*`, and thank you!